# Ways to notify interested autistic contacts of next meetings

Tags: small-communities, email

I manage a mensual meeting on a very specific subject (HIQ *and* autistic spectrum), in a western megapole of 10 million people. Approximatively 40 people have come to one of my 20 activities organized so far.

How can I inform them about dates and subjects of next activities, given that people on the autistic spectrum have problems dealing with communication?

I have so far collected e-mails and phone numbers, and use mainly mail (in BCC) because it is easier. Initially they all gave me permission for that; some of them changed their mind and I took them out of my mailing list.

I also text to one person who said they prefered texting over e-mail but this is difficult.

These is an agenda on a password-protected website, but no blog, Facebook page, Twitter account. One possible complication using these is that I am vision-impaired, hence am easily overloaded by notifications.

Comment: Nope. I am even not on Facebook, difficult to maintain because of my autistic traits. I may finally find a member that is willing to do that; or to integrate another country-wide association that focuses on children but started to include adutles for themeselves, and is on facebook...

Comment: I tried to build something on rizzoma.com but this is not working so far.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I forgot to state that I am vision-impaired, hence am easily overloaded by notifications. But if the answer states that I should turn to facebook, l'll do, except that everyone at work will know about my autistric traits.

Comment: I don't use Facebook either.  I was asking in order to understand what push notifications might already be available to your community, in case that's an option.  (Not necessarily noisy push; I was also thinking of RSS.  It all depends in what people are already using; asking people to adopt a new tool just for your community is a losing proposition.)

Comment: Different autistic people may have different communication problems. Could you specify what sorts of issues you anticipate and want help solving?

Comment: @V2Blast Some autistic people have a mailbox or a Facebook Notification so full that they just cannot cope. They may have disabled notifications. A very similar community has been built by someone I know, on Facebook. This is not perfect but has reached critical mass (50 users) so that unanswered statuses are now seldom. But all do at least in a certain measure restrain giving details about their life because trusting Facebook made it difficult to trust them. If only this was created on a more friendly media. I wished https://joinmobilizon.org/en/ would have been created earlier.

Comment: @user2987828: ...That was quite a bit "later in the week" :P I forgot I even commented here. You should edit your clarification into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of using an events website?

Something like meetup.com or eventbrite etc? They are usually free for community groups. There are different privacy settings. Meetup.com is probably more vision-impaired friendly than the others. There is an app which allows for the accessibility tools to be used on the phone.

Comment: Thans @Poidah for your answer. I don't much like meetup because they are both invading privacy and asking for money (10$ a month). See additional details in my comment https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/ways-to-notify-interested-autistic-contacts-of-next-meetings#comment3456_2914

Comment: Have you thought of using group sms? If you create a group consisting of all your members, some phones allow you to sms them as if it is one person. That may be worth trying out